# How to implement SHA256 on Java Card 2.2.1?

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard, sha256, javacard, message-digest

I'm trying to implement RSA sign on Java Card version 2.2.1. I have implemented RSA 2048 and tested this successfully, but when trying to hash using the `MessageDigest` class, I'm unable to get the correct answer in response.

Here is my code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA, false);
md.reset();
md.doFinal(toSign, bOffset, bLength, tempBuffer, (short) 0);`
```

But I do not get the correct answer; neighther for `ALG_SHA` nor for `ALG_MD5`.

I'm wondering what the problem is. All samples I have seen use the same methods and parameters.

Comment: We need the full sample code and your tests to verify anything...

Comment: Beside that, `MessageDigest.ALG_SHA` is NOT SHA256 as suggested in your topic headline

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcalgtest/table.html) for some summary of cards supporting both RSA2048 and SHA256. JC 2.2.1 cards that support SHA256 are marked as 'suspicious yes'...good luck!

Comment: @vlp Thanks for that remark. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java Card 2.2.1 specification does not support SHA-256 (or any of the other SHA-2 message digests). It only supports SHA1 and MD5, two complete different cryptographic hash functions. Consequently, neither `MessageDigest.ALG_SHA` nor `MessageDigest.ALG_MD5` will get you an instance of `MessageDigest` that could calculate the SHA-256 hash function.

Only Java Card 2.2.2 and onwards supports various SHA2 functions. In that specification, the `MessageDigest` class would also support

- SHA-256: `MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_256`,
- SHA-384: `MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_384`, and
- SHA-512: `MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_512`.

So if you are lucky and your card actually supports Java Card 2.2.2, you could actually use those constants to obtain a proper `MessageDigest` object.

If your card does not support Java Card 2.2.2, then, of course, you <strike>can't use</strike> *should not<sup>1</sup> be able to use* those constants. You could still check the manual of your card if it supports some proprietary implementation of the `MessageDigest` that also has support for SHA-256, though I highly doubt that.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Thanks to [vlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128464/vlp) for pointing out that there are actually cards that are Java Card 2.2.1 (or below) that seemingly support using the constants for SHA-2 algorithms introduced in the Java Card 2.2.2 API. This might just be caused by other implementation bugs and nobody seems to have tested if these algorithms actually work on those cards. See the [JCAlgTest list](https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcalgtest/table.html) for findings on that.